# mystring gets populated with only final record

Tags: c#

```
    Sqlreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();        //sqlreader reading rows from a database table 
        displaytable disp = new displaytable(); //class with fields regno,name,age,sex

        List<displaytable> mystring = new List<displaytable>();

        while (SQLreader.Read())
        {

            disp._regno = reader.GetString(0);
            disp._name = reader.GetString(1);
            disp._age = reader.GetInt32(2);
            disp._sex = reader.GetString(3);
            mystring.Add(disp);
          //  mystring.Insert(i++, disp);
        }
        con.Close();
        return mystring;
                                    "
```

the above code is used to retrieve the rows from a datatable to a list.
the sample rows are
             0001   aaaa  25  male
             0002   bbbb  26  female
             0003   cccc  28  male    and this is the expected output.

But unfortunately my code is wrong somewhere which gives me the output as

```
         0003   cccc  28  male
         0003   cccc  28  male
         0003   cccc  28  male
```

I tried the list converting all row fields to strings and i got the exact result which  i need, 
but its not working with class objects. please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are updating and inserting the very same object of `displaytable`. Move creation of the object into the cycle:

```
while (SQLreader.Read())
{
    displaytable disp = new displaytable();
    disp._regno = reader.GetString(0);
    disp._name = reader.GetString(1);
    disp._age = reader.GetInt32(2);
    disp._sex = reader.GetString(3);
    mystring.Add(disp);
}
```

Comment: but each time inside the loop i'm updating the values of displaytable class. wont it reflect on the object eventhoung declared outside the loop?

Comment: @user2689298, unless these fields are static (I am pretty sure they are not) - no, it won't affect. Note that you are settings properties of an instance of a class, a single object. Updating its fields does not affect other objects.

Comment: each time i am altering the values of same object instance and adding them to the list, next time when the loop runs again i'm altering the object values and appending it to the list. So practically the list will be having different object instant value??? Sorry if i am talking nonsense..

Comment: @user2689298, with the code from the answer on each iteration you are creating new object (with operator `new`), set its properties and adding reference to it to the list. This is absolutely normal - list is supposed to contain references to different object. Compare this to original code - object was created once, the on each iteration its properties were updated and reference to this object (always the same reference, and the same object!) was inserted to the list.